# Iterate features added by my code?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How can I iterate features my users have added to a google.maps.map?

I can do this with the data layer just fine -- features added by map.data.loadGeoJson().

But how do I find other features without duplicating the data in the map?

Examples:
* Markers the user has added with my DrawingManager? 
* Overlays I have added with code?

Using events and stuff to track everything seems redundant because the data is in the map. Most mapping libraries let programmers iterate the layers of a map and get the features in those layers. Is this missing from Google Maps?

Comment: `Is this missing from Google Maps?` - perhaps the answer lies in google maps API documentation

Comment: Can someone please confirm there is no API to iterate my objects in the map (except data layer)?

Thanks for your reply, Jaromanda. That's the point of this question - the answer does *not* lie in the documentation. But it is hard to believe it is not in the API. So I have asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overlays and features are given a map, but there isn't a documented circular reference in which the map is given the features.

This means there is no central storage nor reference in the API to access drawn features/overlays. There might be an undocumented property somewhere, but these are unreliable and do change names pretty often.